# Selecting lines affected by sea level rise?

Tags: qgis, dem, elevation, climate, sea-level-rise

I'm doing a part for my master's thesis where I'm trying to find out which sites located near the coasts of Sweden that will be affected by sea level rise. I got a DEM with height data and have to select features from lines, points and polygons .shp layers.

I can figure out how to select the points and polygons using a raster calculator mask, but I have troubles with the lines .shp layer.

Is there any method of selecting the lines features that get affected by sea level rise?

Perhaps an alternative method to using raster calculator for simulating sea level rise or some tool that will work with .shp layers and rasters similar to zonal statistics, but for lines?

Answer (score 1):

You could transform the sea level rise raster to a vector format. Than you can use an intersection analysis to select the lines that are affected.